# Do strawberries in Celeste Classic (Pico-8) count toward the level strawberries?

Tags: nintendo-switch, celeste

There's several strawberries that can be collected in the hidden mini-game Celeste Classic on the Pico-8 terminal.

Does collecting all of them count toward the level strawberry count? Or is the mini-game completely irrelevant to the game stats except for Xbox/PS4 achievements?

I'm playing on a Switch, so it feels like a lot of work for no actual reward (except the personal satisfaction of getting to the summit).

Comment: A Google search returns [this](https://www.trueachievements.com/forum/viewthread.aspx?tid=1010570#:~:text=No.) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/celestegame/comments/7whnpl/do_the_strawberries_in_the_pico8_version_count/) among others, so no they don't count.

Comment: @xtropicalsoothing You know that's what the Answer option is for, right? Quite the entire point of this platform :)

Comment: @Joachim Even when my answer isn't original and is just linking to sources that I've found somewhere else?

Comment: @xtropicalsoothing Users often find their answers elsewhere on the internet. It's just a matter of rephrasing it, putting it into your own words, and link to your sources if you quote them or think they might be useful for the person asking the question (or users with similar questions).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The strawberries inside the PICO-8 mini-game don't count for any achievement. And for that matter, the game might not even keep track of how many you collect.

So the PICO-8 mini-game is irrelevant to your global number of strawberries. Beating it only counts for its own achievement of beating it. (Note: the achievements are only on PlayStation, Xbox and PC, but not Switch that has no achievements as of February 2022).

Sources:

- https://www.trueachievements.com/forum/viewthread.aspx?tid=1010570
- https://www.reddit.com/r/celestegame/comments/7whnpl/do_the_strawberries_in_the_pico8_version_count/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/celestegame/comments/a1tv1p/pico8_strawberries/
- https://steamcommunity.com/app/504230/discussions/0/1697168437861085535/
- https://steamcommunity.com/app/504230/discussions/0/1692659769960955045/